# remove Div on click with confirmation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am not good at JavaScript and jQuery. I want to remove a `div` after clicking on a `.close` anchor link but I want a confirmation dialog box to appear before removing the `div`.

Secondly, it's removing all the `div` when `.close` anchor link is clicked but I want to close only the `div` that is clicked not all others along with confirmation dialog box to remove it or not.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".close").click(function(){
    $(".default-address").remove();
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".close").click(function(){
    $(".other-address").remove();
  });
});
```

```css
.default-address {
  float:left;
  margin:10px;
  color:#fff;
  width: 46%;
  box-shadow:1px 2px 14px 0px rgba(61, 68, 30, 0.41);
  -webkit-box-shadow:1px 2px 14px 0px rgba(61, 68, 30, 0.41);
  -moz-box-shadow:1px 2px 14px 0px rgba(61, 68, 30, 0.41);
  background-color: #c2d91f;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.default-address ul, .default-address li {
  color: #717f1a;
  list-style: none outside none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px;
}
.default-address ul li span {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.default-address ul li:nth-child(n+1) {
  background-color: #f0f4d7;
}
.default-address ul li:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background-color: #f9fce3;
}
.address-head {
  margin:10px;
}
  a.close {
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
  float:right;
  color:#fff;
  background-color:#a1b41b;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration:none;
}
a.close:hover {
  background-color:#879717;
}
.other-address {
  background-color: #c2d91f;
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 46%;
}
.other-address ul {
  color: #717f1a;
  list-style: none outside none;
  margin: 0 0 1px;
  padding: 0;
}
.other-address li {
  padding: 5px;
}
.other-address ul li span {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.other-address ul li:nth-child(n+1) {
  background-color: #f0f4d7;
}
.other-address ul li:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background-color: #f9fce3;
}
@media (max-width:768px){
  .default-address, .other-address {
    width:96%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="default-address">
  <div class="address-head">
    <strong>1. Address </strong>
    <a class="close" href="#">X</a>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><strong>First Name:</strong><span>First Name Here</span></li>
    <li><strong>Last Name:</strong><span>Last Name Here</span></li>
    <li><strong>Address:</strong><span>User Address</span></li>
    <li><strong>City:</strong><span>User City Name</span></li>
    <li><strong>Area:</strong><span>User Area Detail</span></li>
   </ul>
</div>

<div class="other-address">
  <div class="address-head">
    <strong>1. Address </strong>
    <a class="close" href="#">X</a>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><strong>First Name:</strong><span>First Name Here</span></li>
    <li><strong>Last Name:</strong><span>Last Name Here</span></li>
    <li><strong>Address:</strong><span>User Address</span></li>
    <li><strong>City:</strong><span>User City Name</span></li>
    <li><strong>Area:</strong><span>User Area Detail</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="other-address">
  <div class="address-head">
    <strong>1. Address </strong>
 <a class="close" href="#">X</a>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><strong>First Name:</strong><span>First Name Here</span></li>
    <li><strong>Last Name:</strong><span>Last Name Here</span></li>
    <li><strong>Address:</strong><span>User Address</span></li>
    <li><strong>City:</strong><span>User City Name</span></li>
    <li><strong>Area:</strong><span>User Area Detail</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="other-address">
  <div class="address-head">
    <strong>1. Address </strong>
 <a class="close" href="#">X</a>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><strong>First Name:</strong><span>First Name Here</span></li>
    <li><strong>Last Name:</strong><span>Last Name Here</span></li>
    <li><strong>Address:</strong><span>User Address</span></li>
    <li><strong>City:</strong><span>User City Name</span></li>
    <li><strong>Area:</strong><span>User Area Detail</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="other-address">
  <div class="address-head">
    <strong>1. Address </strong>
    <a class="close" href="#">X</a>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><strong>First Name:</strong><span>First Name Here</span></li>
    <li><strong>Last Name:</strong><span>Last Name Here</span></li>
    <li><strong>Address:</strong><span>User Address</span></li>
    <li><strong>City:</strong><span>User City Name</span></li>
    <li><strong>Area:</strong><span>User Area Detail</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="other-address">
  <div class="address-head">
    <strong>1. Address </strong>
 <a class="close" href="#">X</a>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><strong>First Name:</strong><span>First Name Here</span></li>
    <li><strong>Last Name:</strong><span>Last Name Here</span></li>
    <li><strong>Address:</strong><span>User Address</span></li>
    <li><strong>City:</strong><span>User City Name</span></li>
    <li><strong>Area:</strong><span>User Area Detail</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a8be0eae/) is clearer for all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
$(".close").click(function(){
    var confirmVal = confirm("Do you really want to remove the default address part?");

    if(confirmVal) {
        $(this).closest("div").parent().remove();
    } else {
        // cancel button clicked
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/msuL0yta/165/)

Please edit the confirmation dialog message according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

Try the DEMO [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/s3ubqg0x/)

First remove the Duplicate code in your script tag and use the following code for you solution

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".close").click(function () {
            var $conf = confirm("Do you really want to remove this data?")
            if($conf)
                $(this).closest("div").parent().remove();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is:

## [confirm()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.confirm)

For instance:

```
if (window.confirm("Do you really want to leave?")) { 
  //your code
}
```

Comment: that is just one part of the OP's question.